# What is the key of a JSON-encoded String

Tags: java, php, json

I have a Java application communicating with a SQL database via a PHP script, using JSON. I have used JSON before to json_encode an array, that works fine, you can call the values in Java by using the key of each entry. But now, I json_encoded a string in PHP, like this:
`json_encode("Succes!");` 
Now, how do I request that value in the Java side of business? I need something to put into `jsonResponse.getString('key');` as a key. What is the key...

I hope you understand my question...

```
public String send(String username, String password, String database){
    //Create a HTTPClient as the form container
    HttpClient httpclient;

//Use HTTP POST method
HttpPost httppost;

//Create an array list for the input data to be sent
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

//Create a HTTP Response and HTTP Entity
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;

//Create new default HTTPClient
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

//Create new HTTP POST with URL to php file as parameter
httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.144.150/login/add.php");

String pass = md5(password);

//Next block of code needs to be surrounded by try/catch block for it to work
try {
    //Create new Array List
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    //place them in an array list
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("database", database));

    //Add array list to http post
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    //assign executed form container to response
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    //check status code, need to check status code 200
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200){

        //assign response entity to http entity
        entity = response.getEntity();

        //check if entity is not null
        if(entity != null){


            //Create new input stream with received data assigned
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            //Create new JSON Object. assign converted data as parameter.
            //JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
            JSONArray a = new JSONArray(convertStreamToString(instream));

            //assign json responses to local strings
            String res = a.getString(0);

            //Return the json response to the gui
            return res;

        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "kapot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return new String("De entiteit is leeg. Kortom: kapot");
        }


    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "statuscode was niet 200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return new String("De statuscode was niet 200.");
    }


} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    //Display toast when there is a connection error
    //Change message to something more friendly
    //Toast.makeText(this, "verbindingsproblemem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return new String("Er is een fout opgetreden. Controleer a.u.b. uw gegevens en de internetverbinding.");
}
```

Don't mind the Dutch parts, it's unimportant.

Comment: What Java JSON library are you using?

Comment: Java !== Javascript... do you mean java or javascript?

Comment: I mean Java of course, otherwise it would have said Javascript in my question...

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: No need to be snippy, you wouldn't believe how many JavaScript questions are tagged `java` by the OP. :-) And since you mention using PHP (so the server is PHP), it makes it even more reasonable for Mark to wonder if you'd just misspoken (since it's unclear where Java fits into your scenario, if the server is PHP). Separately: Would you answer my question above?

Comment: ah yes sorry then. I am using the org.json library.

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13136837/157247) to show you how to do this with org.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `json_encode("Success!")` is `"Success"`, which isn't in and of itself a valid [JSON document](http://json.org). A valid JSON document's top-level entity (the root) must be an object or an array.

If you want to just return a single string, you might do that by:

1. Making it the only entry in an array:

   ```
   json_encode(array("Success!"))
   ```

   ...which results in `["Success!"]`, which you can use like this in your Java code (since you say you're using the `org.java` library):

   ```
   JSONArray a = new JSONArray(jsonStringFromPHP);
   String s = a.getString(0);
   ```

   or of course

   ```
   String s = new JSONArray(jsonStringFromPHP).getString(0);
   ```
2. Or making it the only property of an object:

   ```
   json_encode(array('result' => "Success!")
   ```

   ...which results in `{"result":"Success!"}`, which you can use like this in your Java code:

   ```
   JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonStringFromPHP);
   String s = o.getString("result");
   ```

or of course

```
    String s = new JSONObject(jsonStringFromPHP).getString("result");
```

You could probably use [`JSONTokenizer`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html) to read your current JSON *fragment* (`"Success!"`), but I wouldn't suggest going that way. Stick to exchanging valid JSON documents.

Comment: Ah and do i still need to use the InputStream for the PHP response?

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: What `InputStream`? You didn't mention one in your qustion, and I didn't mention one in my answer, so I'm confused. :-) `JSONObject`, `JSONArray`, and `JSONTokenizer` are all happy to work with a `String` as input (or an `InputStream`, either way).

Comment: Hmm i guess I'll post my entire code then. Please check main question for that :)

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: I haven't used that library, but assuming that the `InputStream` you get from `HttpEntity` will return the JSON document when it's read, `JSONArray a = new JSONArray(instream);` should work (without the need for the call to convert it to a string first) -- assuming you've changed your PHP to send the response as I listed in option 1 above. If it doesn't work, that suggests that other information (headers?) is being returned as part of the stream.

Comment: it returns: `org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.`

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: My mistake, `JSONArray` doesn't have a `JSONArray(InputStream)` constructor: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#constructor_summary I thought it did. So you'd want to do your read-it-all-into-a-string thing first (because it *does* have a `JSONArray(String)` constructor). Or alternately `JSONArray a = new JSONArray(new JSONTokenizer(instream))`, as there's a `JSONArray(JSONTokenizer)` and a `JSONTokenizer(InputStream)`.

Comment: JSONTokener, you mean? Tokenizer does not exist in the package I have.

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: Yes, `JSONTokener`. ("Tokener" is a very odd term for it, but apparently it's what they used.)

Comment: `org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]` is what I get. Shall i post my PHP code as well?

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: See my comments above. You need to make the change I listed in Option 1, **and** you need to ensure that the data returned by the `InputStream` is just the body of the JSON document, that it doesn't have any other stuff in it (such as headers). Sorry, that's all the help I can give you.

Comment: It's working already. Turns out i forgot to change one of the `json_encode` statements to use an array. -.- Thank you very much for your help, accepted and upvoted.

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel: Ah, good, I like it when there's a simple explanation! Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any key

In PHP

```
json_encode("Succes!"); // returns "Succes!"
```

In Javascript [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('"Succes!"');
alert(obj);
```

In Java [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

```
Object obj = JSONValue.parse("\"Succes!\"");
System.out.println(obj);
```

**Edit Ref : @DaveRandom**

> The [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) requires that JSON is wrapped in an array or an object, as it states:
>
> | A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> Anything that follows the spec strictly shouldn't accept just "string" or number literals or boolean literals (scalar values) on their own - but I suspect many parsers will, as often parsers are designed to forgive small deviations from the standard. Which is annoying, because it means people then deviate from the standard without a problem, and wonder why they run into problems later when they use a stricter implementation.
>
> There is an argument that it should return NULL instead in this situation, but with the way it behaves you are able to manually construct parts of the JSON string yourself, and get other parts from json_encode()
>
> ...of course, you shouldn't/wouldn't do this, but you can.
>
> Just think of it like XML - you can't have a valid XML document without a root node. They are both designed for representing vectors and complex structures, the assumption being that if you have simple/scalar data to transmit, you can just pass it directly.

Comment: Your answer didn't address the question. Now you've added the Java bit at the end, it at least vaguely comes close to answering it. The fundamental issue with the OP's code, though, is that the JSON is incomplete. A JSON parser isn't obliged to be willing to part it at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you must access your JSON data by key in your Java app, your best bet would be to:

```
json_encode(array('message' => 'Success!'));
```

Then in Java (according to your sample code):

```
jsonResponse.getString('message');
```

Comment: Thank you, trying now.
I get: `org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]` followed by a huge stacktrace that i won't bother you with...

Comment: Well, `json_encode(array('message' => 'Success!'));` results in the JSON string `{"message":"Success!"}` which does start with '{'. Not sure what is going wrong there.

Comment: no me neither. I looke further into the stacktrace, the error actually originates from a different line of code: `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));`